# Photogallery with last/next photo. How does it work?

Tags: php

I want to make a photo gallery for my users and I want it to look like this:

last img. img. next img.

`<-    []   ->`

I wonder if someone could explain how the last/next image link/button works. 
I use mysqli and i have imgID, imgURL etc stored in the db

Comment: Well... everything depends on what you have tried this far to create it and what yor datasource will be.

Comment: I use mysqli and i have imgID etc

Comment: Too broad and unclear/no code to work with. Look up pagination, it's available in a few platforms also, such as jQuery/Ajax.

Comment: You should do your own research and only post on stack if you have a particular question related to code. This is a concept question that could have a billion answers and a billion different approaches. You need to pick your own approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention you have an imgID stored in the database. 
when someone clicks on the 'Next' button, pick the id of the image that is currently showing. 
Query the database to find out the next higher (or lower, based on whatever sort), imgID. 
Then fetch its URL.
Show that image, in the same way, however you are showing the current image.